# Missing plot for double derivative with log

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, numerical-integration, complex

I want to plot the given code of double derivate with log function. My derivative is a function of delta P. But when I run the code, I never see the plot.

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"]

plotset = {FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.004]], 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 18]};

plotset2 = FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, 18],  Directive[FontOpacity -> 0,
  FontSize -> 0]}, {Directive[Black, 18], Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]}};

\[Gamma]1 = 2*Pi*1.7;
\[Gamma]3 = 2*Pi*55;
\[Gamma]2 = 2*Pi*6.9;
\[Gamma]4 = 0; (*add definition from comment*)

\[CapitalGamma]32 = \[Gamma]3 + \[Gamma]2;
\[CapitalGamma]43 = \[Gamma]4 + \[Gamma]3;
\[Delta]c = 0*\[Gamma]4;

\[Gamma]0 = 0;
\[CapitalOmega]C = 1.5*\[Gamma]3; 
\[CapitalGamma]02 = \[Gamma]2;
\[CapitalOmega]s = 0.25*\[CapitalOmega]C; 
\[CapitalOmega]P = 0.01*\[CapitalOmega]C;
\[Delta]s = -0.5*\[CapitalOmega]C;
\[CapitalGamma]43 = \[Gamma]4 + \[Gamma]3; 

\[Delta]sc = \[Delta]s - \[Delta]c;
\[Delta]ps = \[Delta]p - \[Delta]s; 
\[Delta]pc = \[Delta]p - \[Delta]c; 

\[Rho]00 = 0.4; 
\[Rho]22 = 0.6; 
\[Rho]33 = 0;

\[Xi] = (\[CapitalGamma]32 + 2*I*\[Delta]s
  + \[CapitalOmega]C^2/(\[Gamma]1 + \[Gamma]2 + 2*I*\[Delta]sc));

r = \[CapitalGamma]02*((\[Rho]00 - \[Rho]33)*(\[Xi])
  + (\[Rho]33 - \\[Rho]22)*\[CapitalOmega]s^2/(\[Gamma]2
  - 2*I*\[Delta]ps))/(\[Xi]*(\[Gamma]3
  - 2*I*\[Delta]p + \[CapitalOmega]C^2/(\[Gamma]1
  - 2*I*\[Delta]pc) + \[CapitalOmega]s^2/(\[Gamma]2 - 2*I*\[Delta]ps)));

\[Phi] = ( L*\[Omega]p)/c;
L = 1*10^-3 ;
\[Omega]p = 2*Pi*10.5*10^9;
c = 3*10^8;

\[Zeta]1 = Exp[2*I*\[Phi]]*(1 - 2*r) - 1;
\[Zeta]2 = -Exp[2*I*\[Phi]]*(1 - 2*r) - 1;
\[Theta] = Sqrt[(Exp[2*I*\[Phi]] - 1)*(Exp[2*I*\[Phi]]*(1 - 2*r)^2 - 1)];

M11 = ((\[Zeta]1 + \[Theta])*((\[Zeta]2 + \[Theta])^n)
  - (\[Zeta]1 - \[Theta])*((\[Zeta]2
  - \[Theta])^n) )/(2^(n + 1)*Exp[I*(n - 1)*\[Phi]]*\[Theta]*(r - 1)^n);

T1 = Abs[1/M11]^2;
uu = Log[T1];
```

The next line is a second order partial derivate with respect to delta p. This is the equation which I want to plot.

```
rr1 = -2*Sqrt[(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Delta]p, \[Delta]p\)]uu\))^-1];
\[Delta]p = -(\[CapitalOmega]C/2);

h1 = Plot[rr1, {n, 0, 150}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 450,
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.007]}}, GridLines -> Automatic,
  FrameLabel -> {Style["", 18, Bold],  Style["", 18, Bold]}, 
  Evaluate@plotset, Evaluate@plotset2, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: What is the value assigned to `γ4`  or `\[Gamma]4`? That variable is used but the assignment is not shown. Next please explain in words, not subscripts and special characters, exactly what this line `rr1 = -2\*Sqrt[(!(*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), ([Delta]p, [Delta]p)]uu))^-1]` is supposed to calculate. It appears you are trying to take the derivative of something but the special characters and copy and paste have ruined that line and I cannot understand exactly what you want that to do.

Comment: γ4 =0; rr1 = -2\*Sqrt[(!(*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), ([Delta]p, [Delta]p)]uu))^-1] This is an equation which I have also shown in the question. Basically, it is a second-order derivate with respect to delta p

Comment: γ4 =o.  This line rr1 = -2\*Sqrt[(!(*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), ([Delta]p, [Delta]p)]uu))^-1] is a second order partial derivate with respect to delta p. This is an equation which I want to plot. I also put the fig of this equation in the question.

Comment: You have a syntax error ` \\[Rho]22` should read ` \[Rho]22`. Then your expression gives a complex result and this is the reason no plot is shown. You may e.g. use "ReIm" or "ComplexPlot"

Comment: @creidhne You went over and above to clean up the code!  Thanks!

Comment: @abdulwahab Pretend you are me for a minute. Start Mathematica fresh. Scrape `rr1 = -2*Sqrt[(!(*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), ([Delta]p, [Delta]p)]uu))^-1]` off the computer screen and paste it into MMA. Do you see the red `[(` in that which shows that Mathematica does not understand that and thinks that are an error? Or if you start MMA, scrape and paste `rr1 = -2*Sqrt[(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Delta]p, \[Delta]p\)]uu\))^-1]` then it shows 12 red characters that it thinks are an error. That was what I was trying to get you to see. That is what keeps others from trying to help you.